# Postman и Rest Client в VS Code

Tags: api, rest, request, postman

Отправляя один и тот же запрос разными методами я не получаю ответа отправляя запрос через Rest Client (расширениее для VS Code)

#### Запрос через Rest Client

[image: Запрос через Rest Client]

#### Запрос через Postman

[image: Запрос через Postman]

#### Код обработки запроса

[image: Код обработки запроса]

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?
P.S в postman content-type: application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пустую строку нельзя вставлять произвольно - она служит для отделения заголовка от тела запроса, у вас же она стоит перед `Content-Type: application/json` и эта строка вместо заголовка попадает в тело запроса.

Правильный формат:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "login": "sample",
    "password": "sample"
}
```